# Inserting/Updating MySQL table via PHP, row will update but not insert.

Tags: php, mysql

Im not very experienced in PHP and would appreciate any help! Im am sending a username, longitude and latitude to my server using HTTP Post. I first check if the user exists in the `user_info` table. If it does then i try to update the `maps_user_location` table with that username. What i want to happen is that if the query fails, due to the username not being found in `maps_user_location` table, then i want it to be added. I've tried to do it with the code below.

```
$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)
or
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);

$latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
$longitude = $_POST['longitude'];
$username = $_POST['username'];

if ($latitude != 0 && $longitude != 0) {
    $query_userCheck = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE login_username = '".$username."';";
    if ( mysql_query($query_userCheck) ) {
        $query_updateLocation =  "UPDATE  `maps_user_location` SET  `lat` =  '".$latitude."',`long` =  '".$longitude."' WHERE  
        `login_username` = '".$username."';";
        if ( !mysql_query($query_updateLocation) ){
            $query_newLocation = "INSERT INTO `maps_user_location` ( `id` ,`login_username` ,`lat` ,`long` ,`track`)
            VALUES ( NULL ,  '".$username."',  '".$latitude."',  '".$longitude."',  '0');";

            mysql_query($query_newLocation);
        }

    }
}
```

When i execute the code, it goes through without a hitch. The problem is that a row is never inserted if the username does not exist already, the row does update if the username exists though. Additionally, when i add a row manually, the id column seems to increment after every request (the sequence will go 1,2,3,4,10,11,12...etc [the ids 5-9 do not exist]). I have a feeling that it has to do with the 'WHERE' in '$query_updateLocation'. Anyone have any clue as to why this happens?

Comment: you have a total lack of any error handling in there, and are simply assuming your code and queries are working perfectly. the very BARE MINIMUM you should have is `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error())`. You are also wide-open to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: The parameters in the post request are defined by myself so SQL injection isn't possible. Thank you for the heads up though. I've added the die() function as you've suggested. Thanks again!

Comment: that's exactly the **WRONG** way to think about it. There is not such thing as a "safe" post. If your script is receiving data from a user, you have to treat that user as hostile/malicious. It is **BEYOND TRIVIAL** to fake a post and submit anything you want.

Comment: understood, ill implement the changes. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do that in a single query, Use **[`INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)**

```
INSERT INTO  maps_user_location ( login_username , lat, long, track)
VALUES ('".$username."',  '".$latitude."', '".$longitude."',  '0')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
             lat    =  '".$latitude."' ,
            long  =  '".$longitude."'
```

but before anything else, make sure that you have  a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` on the column `login_username`. If you have not added, you can alter your table using this command

```
ALTER TABLE maps_user_location ADD UNIQUE (login_username);
```

Comment: That did the trick, minor syntax error but i got it resolved quickly. Thank you!